# Is ssh port forwarding an acceptable way to communicate with internal API services?

Tags: ssh, soa

Is you're building a distributed architecture with various services, is it acceptable to have those services communicate via ssh port forwarding, so that to a client a service looks like it's being served on a local port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only person who can answer "is it acceptable" is you, or your client.

Is it wise?  Probably not, because SSL with certificates at both ends will deliver the same capability with a much less troublesome intermediate layer, but that is an engineering decision you have to make.

Comment: Do you mean to set up VPN with SSL or how would you use SSL for generic TCP communication (the OP did not specify how the services would communicate). I'm curious since I have used the port forwarding or SOCKS via ssh when VPN was not possible. Always looking for new solutions.

Comment: I meant literally SSL secured communication, either layered under something like HTTP, or just securing the TCP connection raw - because that is the closest match to what ssh gives, with the auth of both ends, and the point-to-point link.  The basic problem is that ssh isn't designed to be a "service", rather an interactive tool, so it more or less sucks as the basis for your deployment in terms of robustness.